# In Grails, how to Expose a GroovyWS?

Tags: grails, groovyws

In grails where would you place an exposed webservice using GroovyWS plugin? Also where would you place the methods as in [the example online](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Publishing+a+web-service)? I feel like newing a `WSServer` is the wrong approach since we are working on a Spring-MVC framework.

```
def server = new WSServer() 
server.setNode("MathService", "http://localhost:6980/MathService") 
server.start()
```

Should I be using the Apache CXF plugin instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using the jaxRS plugin or just plainly expose your action for a controller via url mapping. In the action you can call a service method. You can use CXF but it would be a overkill because it uses SOAP.